# How to use SQLSyntaxSupport with a case class containing other case classes

Tags: postgresql, scala, scalikejdbc

I'm trying to use Scalikejbdc's ORM with SQLSyntaxSupport

The table layout is as follows:

```
create table samples (
    id text
    event_name text
    event_data text
    created_at timestamp
    scope text
)
```

The classes in Scala are as follows

```
case class SampleData(id: String, eventName: String, eventData: String)
case class SampleMetadata(createdAt: OffsetDateTime, scope: String)
case class Sample(data: SampleData, metadata: SampleMetadata)
```

I would like to use SQLSyntaxSupport like so

```
object SampleSchema extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Sample] {
  override val tableName = "sources"

  override lazy val columns = Seq(
    "id",
    "event_name",
    "event_data",
    "created_at",
    "scope"
  )

  val insertColumns = Seq(
    column.id,
    column.eventName,
    column.eventData,
    column.createdAt,
    column.scope
  )
}
```

and later be able to do:

```
  def insert(source: Source): Unit = DB localTx { implicit session =>
      applyUpdate {
        insertInto(SampleSchema)
          .columns(SampleSchema.insertColumns: _*)
          .values(SampleSchema.toInsertValues(session, source): _*)
      }
  }
```

Code doesn't compile; with errors like

```
 Sample#eventName not found. Expected fields are #data, #metadata
 column.eventName
```

Is there a way to make it work without flattening the `case class Sample` ?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use `Seq(column.data.id, column.data.eventName, column.data.eventData, column.metadata.createdAt, column.metadata.scope)` instead of `Seq(column.id, column.eventName, column.eventData, column.createdAt, column.scope)`?

Comment: this wouldn't work. I tried it and it appears that we can't do something like `column.data.XXX`